# Xcode suddenly hang when I design my storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to ask about Xcode.
When I designing my storyboard, suddenly my Xcode force quit.
And after that, if I open my project storyboard file it will loading forever.
Eventhough I create new project, the storyboard still loading forever.
But I can open the storyboard as a source code.
Help me please.
Should I reinstal my Xcode ?

Comment: Did you try to restart your Mac?

Comment: it should be your project storyboard xml issue.

Comment: I already tried every solution that I found in stackoverflow like deleted cache folder. But its not work